# what is the meaning of this line of code?

Tags: c++

Here is the code.

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> f() const { return f_; }
```

I understand that `std::share_ptr` is a smart pointer. `MyType` is a template parameter. `f()` is a function, right? `const` here means this function will be read-only. And then what is the relation between the function definition/body and this smart pointer? Many thanks for your comments.
**EDIT：** I just realized that `std::shared_ptr<MyType>` is the function return type from all your comments/answers. Now, my question is, f_ is an object of `std::shared_ptr<MyType>`, is it correct? How do I know that? Do I need to declare the variable `f_` anywhere? This is a piece of code from my working_on project and I did not find it very clear about the variable `f_` or is there anything else I need to know about the relation between method `f` and variable `f_`?

Comment: *"`const` here means this function will be read-only"* Yes, it can't modify the class members. `std::shared_ptr<MyType>` is the return type, or do you already know that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is not a discussion forum or tutorial resource. Feel free to come here when you have a specific question relating to *your own* code (after you have [tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to figure it out yourself, of course). But for something like this, you are better off looking up a tutorial, reading technical documentation, or using an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: `f` is a method, const there means that the method can only be called on cont objects and that it will not modify the object. "what is the relation between the function definition/body and this smart pointer" i am not sure I understand, the method returns a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Tharsalys, no if `f_` is an object of `MyType` this code won't compile, there is no automatic implicit conversion from objects to `shared_ptr`

Comment: @Tharsalys `f_` already has to be `shared_ptr<MyType>` - the function is just returning it.

Comment: I voted to close your question because _relationship_ is too vague a concept to ask for an objective answer.  When you ask "what is the relation between the function definition/body and this smart pointer", it's not really an answerable question.  Like "what is the relationship between a variable and the value assigned to it" or "what is the relationship between a type and a value".  These are equally vague.  What do _you_ think the relationship is?  If you propose a claim, we could at least verify the truth of that claim.  But "what is the relationship" is just too open-ended.

Comment: The `const` here can be thought of as qualifying the implicit `this` that all member functions have. The body of `f()` only reads the data member `f_` (to copy it), so that's fine.

Comment: It looks like f_ is a class field (private or protected, maybe inherited) of type std::shared_ptr<MyType> and f() just a getter to it. But if you provide f_ definition (within the class(es)) your question may be reopened and answered objectively.

Comment: @zhenDong I have shown one possible scenario for variable `f_` as you asked in your edited question. Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code snippet can be read as:

> f is a **const member function** that returns a `std::shared_ptr<MyType>`  that is it returns a `shared_ptr<>` to MyType object.

As you already mentioned that the function is read-only, is there something else you want to ask, if there is you can edit your question. Also,note that the variable `f_` that you're returning from inside the body of function `f` is of type `std::shared_ptr<MyType>` .

**Answer to your Edit**

> Do I need to declare the variable f_ anywhere?

The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/lZDMffQmu) example shows one possible scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class MyType
{
  int value = 0;
  //some other things here 
  public:
      MyType()
      {
          std::cout<<"MyType Default constructor"<<std::endl;
      }
};

class Name 
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyType> f_ = std::make_shared<MyType>(); //note that you can also write std::shared_ptr<MyType> f_{new MyType};
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<MyType> f() const //f is a const member function returning std::shared_ptr<MyType>
        { 
            std::cout<<"inside const member function f"<<std::endl;
            return f_; 
        }  
};

int main()
{
    
  const Name n;
  n.f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/lZDMffQmu).